# Glow effect over text in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I achieve this light blue glow effect over text in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any color I would consider neon. Are you referring to the light blue on top of the white?

Comment: Or maybe you mean the Outer Glow and Drop Shadow?  Effect > Stylize > Outer Glow and Effect > Stylize > Drop Shadow.  The shadow would be light blue and the glow would be white

Comment: While possible in Illustrator, it's more probable that this was created in Photoshop, or some other raster-based application, at least in part. To do this in Illustrator  (and keep it vector) it would take a good understanding of gradient meshes.

Comment: Subtle? Neon? I see a glow. Identify an effect specifically and I may be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. You are right, the term glow is more suitable.

Comment: If "gradient meshes" are best to get this effect in vector format, could the third-party plugin "Mesh Tormentor" for Illustrator be helpful for newbies in this specific case?

Comment: Do you mean the blue or the white?

Comment: The light blue one.

Comment: Mesh Tormentor would not really be that beneficial here. But it may not be completely useless either. Honestly, it just takes a few small meshes with transparent outer mesh points and varying opacity inner points.

Comment: I think you are wasting your time trying to emulate that effect in Illustrator.  The example looks like it was done in Photoshop or at least another raster image editor - much easier to do simply using layer styles there.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You are welcome to show how to do it in Photoshop to help those interested in the effect but in raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the soft glows and highlights, **Gradient Meshes** would probably be a good option if Illustrator must be used.

It just takes a few small meshes to create the highlights.

<sub>(This is NOT perfect and is only included to show the methodology.)</sub>

[image: meshes]

...Meshes with transparent edges then a light blue center.

The outer glows are created by applying the `Feather`, `Transform`, and `Offset` Effect to additional fills. If I were strictly interested in only non-raster objects, I'd create the outer glow/shadow with a mesh as well.

The large dark blue stroke has shadows in it, I'd apply those with small meshes the same way the white highlights are created.